# JPA CriteriaQuery construct results in one SQL per row returned

Tags: hibernate, jpa, criteria, criteria-api

The following code retrieves a list of Persons along with a count of how many dogs they own. One SQL is generated for this query.

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Tuple> query = cb.createTupleQuery();
Root<Person> person = query.from(Person.class);
SetJoin<Person,Dog> dogsJoin = person.join("dogs", JoinType.LEFT);
query.multiselect(
        cb.count(dogsJoin.get("id")).alias("numDogs"),
        person.alias("person")
).groupBy(person);
```

However when I converted the same query to use CriteriaBuilder.construct(), it resulted in one SQL generated PER ROW returned.

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<CountableEntryDto> query = cb.createQuery(CountableEntryDto.class);
Root<Person> person = query.from(Person.class);
SetJoin<Person,Dog> dogsJoin = person.join("dogs", JoinType.LEFT);
query.select(
    cb.construct(CountableEntryDto.class,
                 person,
                 cb.count(dogsJoin.get("id")))
).groupBy(person);
```

Is this because of the switch from multiselect to select? Is there a way to avoid having one SQL generated per row?

EDIT:
The same behavior can be seen using JPQL. The following results in one SQL per row returned, on top of the original query:

```
List resultList = em.createQuery("select new com.example.dto.CountableEntryDto(p, count(dogs)) from Person p left join p.dogs dogs group by p.id").getResultList();
```

results in 4 SQL statements (3 Person entities returned in result list):

```
select person0_.id as col_0_0_, count(dogs1_.id) as col_1_0_ from Person person0_ left outer join Dog dogs1_ on person0_.id=dogs1_.owner_id group by person0_.id
select person0_.id as id32_0_, person0_.age as age32_0_, person0_.firstname as firstname32_0_, person0_.lastname as lastname32_0_ from Person person0_ where person0_.id=?
select person0_.id as id32_0_, person0_.age as age32_0_, person0_.firstname as firstname32_0_, person0_.lastname as lastname32_0_ from Person person0_ where person0_.id=?
select person0_.id as id32_0_, person0_.age as age32_0_, person0_.firstname as firstname32_0_, person0_.lastname as lastname32_0_ from Person person0_ where person0_.id=?
```

But this:

```
List resultList = em.createQuery("select p, count(dogs) from Person p left join p.dogs dogs group by p.id").getResultList();
```

results in only one SQL executed:

```
select person0_.id as col_0_0_, count(dogs1_.id) as col_1_0_, person0_.id as id10_, person0_.age as age10_, person0_.firstname as firstname10_, person0_.lastname as lastname10_ from Person person0_ left outer join Dog dogs1_ on person0_.id=dogs1_.owner_id group by person0_.id
```

I am using Hibernate 4.1.0.Final, Hibernate JPA2 1.0.1.Final and running against Postgres.

Comment: What do you mean exactly with _one SQL generated per row_?

Comment: One SQL statement per Person entity returned in the query.

Comment: Seriously, what do you mean exactly with _one SQL generated per row_? Are you looking at some Hibernate logs? This seems really really strange. In EclipseLink your query works fine and generates obviously only one SQL statement.

Comment: Added SQL generated for clarification

Comment: I see. This is a choice of the jpa provider, in your case Hibernate. In the case of EclipseLink, all the fields are retrieved with one single query, as per your second example.